# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: while importing two libraries built with .so files (ndk files)

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, sqlcipher

For my project I want to use two third party packages: **OCR** and **SQL-Cipher**. However I receive an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when I try to configure both packages. Can you help me figure out what is wrong with my project setup configuration?

The third party packages I am using are:

- **OCR** - `https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two` and for
- **SQL-Cipher** - jar file and .so files in `libs` folder (not `lib` folder)

Configuration is like:

```
libs/armeabi folder
```

1. libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
2. libsqlcipher_android.so
3. libstlport_shared.so

and

```
libs/x86 folder
```

1. libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
2. libsqlcipher_android.so
3. libstlport_shared.so

and jar file named **sqlcipher.jar in libs/** folder all i have imported

When I specify only SQL-Cipher the code works fine but if i also **import tess-two project which is for OCR** at that time i am getting error of SQL-Cipher that **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared** at a time of **SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);**

For the **sql cipher** i have implemented following library into my application i have copied

[image]

now for OCR there is a library project named tess-two which i am importing into my project

[image]

If i import and run i will give an error if i remove tess-two it will successfully run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i have solved my problem by **just removing the armeabi_v7** folder on the new library.